# select all checkbox in magento admin in export attribute grid

Tags: checkbox, magento-1.9

Require a select all checkbox in the grid under the column "skip"

System > Import/export > export
when products is selected for export, a grid is displayed with attributes
so require a checkbox in the table header to select and deselected all the attribute values

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuMgl.png)

Comment: Did you fix this issue?